# How to make array in state and processing to handleFormChange

Tags: javascript, react-native

im newbie in react native, i just implementation react js to native to make handleformchange but i got the error like this "cannot ready propery name of undefined" . i dont know what to do.

this is for react native, running in android and node

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            post : [],
            formData : {
                id : '',
                first_name : '',
                last_name : '' ,
                email : '',
                gender : '',
                password : '',
            }
        }
    } 


getPostAPI () {

        axios.get('http://192.168.100.7:3000/datadiri')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState ({
                post : res.data
            })
        })
    }

sendDataDiri  () {
        axios.post('http://192.168.100.7:3000/datadiri', this.state)
        .then((res) => {

            this.setState ({
                formData : {
                    id : '',
                    first_name : '',
                    last_name : '',
                    email : '',
                    gender : '',
                    password: ''
                }         
            })
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('error : ', err);
        })
    }

handleForm = (e) => {
        let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
        formDataNew[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            formData : formDataNew
        })

    }
render() {
        return (
            <RegisterComponent
                handleFirstChange = {this.handleFirstChange}
                handleLastChange = {this.handleLastChange}
                handleEmailChange = {this.handleEmailChange}
                handleGenderChange = {this.handleGenderChange}
                handlePasswordChange = {this.handlePasswordChange}
                onBackPress = {this.onBackPress}
                handleForm = {this.handleForm}
                onRegisterPress={this.onRegisterPress} 
                first_name = {this.state.formData.first_name}
                last_name = {this.state.formData.last_name}
                email = {this.state.formData.email}
                gender = {this.state.formData.gender}
                password = {this.state.formData.password}
                />
        );
```

RegisterCOmp

```js
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>First Name</Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.textboxfield}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={this.props.handleForm}
                        value={this.props.first_name}
                        placeholder = {'First Name'}
                        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
                        name="first_name"
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Last Name</Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.textboxfield}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={this.props.handleForm}
                        value={this.props.last_name}
                        placeholder = {'Last Name'}
                        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.textboxfield}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={this.props.handleForm}
                        value={this.props.email}
                        placeholder = {'Email'}
                        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Gender</Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.textboxfield}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={this.props.handleForm}
                        value={this.props.gender}
                        placeholder = {'Gender'}
                        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Password </Text>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textboxfield}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    onChangeText={this.props.handleForm}
                    returnKeyType={'done'}
                    value={this.props.password}
                    placeholder = {'Password'}
                    placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
                />
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButtonStyle} onPress={this.props.onRegisterPress}>
                <Text style={styles.loginButtonTextStyle}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.regButtonStyle} onPress={this.props.onBackPress}>
                <Text style={styles.loginButtonTextStyle}>Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>


        </View>
    </View>

        )
    }
}

RegisterComponent.propTypes = {
    handleFirstChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleLastChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleEmailChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleGenderChange: PropTypes.func,
    handlePasswordChange : PropTypes.func,
    onBackPress : PropTypes.func,
    showPassword: PropTypes.func,
    handleForm : PropTypes.func,
    onRegisterPress: PropTypes.func,
    first_name: PropTypes.string,
    last_name: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    gender: PropTypes.string,
    password: PropTypes.string, 
};
```

i need to know how to make e.target.name correct, i just want to put my data to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChangeText` takes a text instead of the event, but there is `onChange` property as well, [check the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchange) for more details.

```
// this method will has text argument but not event
handleForm = (e) => {
  let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
  formDataNew[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

  this.setState({
    formData : formDataNew
  )
}
```

**Updated**

You should modify `handleForm` and `TextInput`:

```
// now it takes field name and value
handleFieldChange = (text, name) => {    
  this.setState({
    formData: {
      ...this.state.formData,
      [name]: text
    }
  });
}

// Register component takes a state of your form
// and method to change fields value
<RegisterComponent
   handleFieldChange={this.handleFirstChange}
   onBackPress={this.onBackPress}
   onRegisterPress={this.onRegisterPress} 
   formState={this.state.formData}
/>

// you can write your fields like this
<TextInput style={styles.textboxfield}
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
  onChangeText={text => this.props.handleFieldChange(text, 'firstName')}
  value={this.props.formState.firstName}
  placeholder = {'First Name'}
  placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
/>

// now you can send your data to the BackEnd
sendData = () => {
  const { formData } = this.state;
  // formData contains values of your fields
}
```

Comment: wohh thankyou, but when i sendthedata to api. return null in json . nothing change like i input firstname aaa, return null in json.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your questions, could you explain in more details, what is your problem?

Comment: okay, i understand when i look the documeentation, but when i want to input data and submit, the data is null in server. but the handleformchange is success no even error again, how to input data then return that i input. is when i call <Register component first_name = {this.state.formData.first_name} ?

Comment: How your `handleForm` and `TextInput` are looking now?

Comment: Look at the code i already display all the code that important

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look, please

Comment: broo one more, function sendData i put on registercomponent or register container ? i have PropTypes in registercontainer . should i put there?

Comment: This function should be in the component which stores form state and sends data to the back end.

Comment: BTW, I saw you make  API request directly form the component, probably right after you make it working you should take look at Redux, it will help you to make your architecture cleaner.

Comment: i got the error bro . undefined is not a object ( evaluating 'this.props.formState.first_name)'

Comment: Hm, probably you have this project on github, so I can take a look?

Comment: already fix it, now i cant type to the textbox. its like when i text something it back to null again, cant write a character

Comment: did yo ustill need my project?  i will put on my github

Comment: yeah i fixed it because of you :)). but why i cant write anycharacter ahhaha.  im still thinking

Comment: Push then your project to github, I'll take a look and give you some advice.

Comment: fixed it ahahhaha, sorry bro. i missing one step. thankkyouu :*